# How to Create Excel using OpenXml package in C#

Tags: c#, excel, email, smtp, openxml

I have attempted this yet I am getting blunders while sending the email Even I don't know whether excel is creating or not. any assistance is valued. Much obliged

I am new to code and using OpenXml Package  need help regarding the below code.

```
namespace CreatingExcel
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.To.Add("rohithajare01@gmail.com");
        mail.From = new MailAddress("rohithajare01@gmail.com");
        mail.Subject = "Test for lookupcode";
        try
        {
            SpreadsheetDocument sd = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(ms,SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);
            WorkbookPart wbp = sd.AddWorkbookPart();
            wbp.Workbook = new Workbook();
            WorksheetPart wsp = wbp.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
            wsp.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());
            Sheets sheets = sd.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());

            Sheet sheet = new Sheet()
            {
                Id = sd.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(wsp),
                SheetId = 1,
                Name = "mySheet"
            };
            sheets.Append(sheet);
            wbp.Workbook.Save();
            wbp.Workbook.sa
            
            
           
            sd.Close();
            byte[] somedata = ms.ToArray();
            

            // ContentType ct = new ContentType(System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.)
            mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(ms, "test.csv", "text/csv"));

            //SmtpClient email = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com",25);

            var email = new SmtpClient();
            email.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            email.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("******@gmail.com", "******");
            email.EnableSsl = true;

            Console.WriteLine("Sending Email..");
            email.Send(mail);
            Console.WriteLine("Email sent");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Console.WriteLine( ex.ToString() );
        }
       
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The console is closing before you can see the error. I suggest you add  `Console.ReadLine();` as the last line of code.

Comment: Try to split this problem in smaller ones. You will be able then to check what's really wrong in your code. 
1. Try to send mail without attachment
2. Try to send mail with some simple attachment like .txt file
3. Generate spreadsheet and save it to local file
After this you will know which process is invalid